# How to reset footnote numbers at every chapter using reledmac?

Tags: numbering, footnotes, reledmac

I'm using the `reledmac` package to give me three-column footnotes for my document. I want the footnote numbering to be reset for each chapter. This was working without me needing to do anything prior to me loading the `reledmac` package. (I am using the `scrbook` class.)

I'm sure there are ways of patching the `\chapter` command to do this. I'm hoping that there is an option in `reledmac` already (that I haven't found in the documentation) that will do this automagically.

---

Here is my minimal working example (not sure how to include the result). This results in footnotes 1,2 from the first chapter and footnote 3 from the second chapter. I would like for the footnote numbering to restart at every chapter.

Please note, I'm not sure of the difference between critical and familiar footnotes.

```tex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{ipsum}

\usepackage[series={A}]{reledmac}
\renewcommand{\footnote}{\footnoteA}
\Xarrangement[A]{threecol}
\arrangementX[A]{threecol}

\title{MWE}

\begin{document}
\chapter{one}
\ipsum<Lang=EN>{}
\footnote{Footnote in chapter 'one'}
\footnote{Another footnote in chapter 'one'}

\chapter{two}
\ipsum<Lang=EN>{}
\footnote{Footnote in chapter 'two'}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Apart from @samcarter's comment, which I totally second, your question is less clear than you might think. `reledmac` has three kinds of footnotes: critical footnotes, critical endnotes, familiar footnotes. Which kind(s) are you interested in?

Comment: Sorry I didn't include a MWE previously. I have included it now so I hope that is more helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to set the counter `footnoteA` reset with `chapter` counter by

```
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{footnoteA}{chapter}
\makeatother
```

The full example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[series={A}]{reledmac}
\renewcommand{\footnote}{\footnoteA}
\Xarrangement[A]{threecol}
\arrangementX[A]{threecol}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{footnoteA}{chapter}
\makeatother

\title{MWE}

\begin{document}
\chapter{one}
\lipsum
\footnote{Footnote in chapter 'one'}
\footnote{Another footnote in chapter 'one'}

\chapter{two}
\lipsum
\footnote{Footnote in chapter 'two'}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]